# Write Code Analyzer with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm experimenting with the .NET Compiler Platform SDK. Currently I want to create an analyzer with code fix as described in this tutorial in the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix.

I followed the steps as described there until there until the second Visual Studio instance opens and there the "Program" identifier should be marked by a wavy unterline.

That worked for me when I tried it with Visual Studio 2019 but I don't get any reaction from the analyzer when I perform the whole stuff with Visual Studio 2022. (According to tutorial it should work on VS2019 or later)

Additionally a project created in this way by VS2022 template works in VS2019.

I used the identical settings in both cases.

Did I miss something? Are there any additional settings necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently (VS2022 v17.1.1) created project from template (Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET standart)) is outdated, only works for vs2019 and need to be updated. I tried to update mine using [Microsoft instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/update-visual-studio-extension?view=vs-2022) but failed miserable. If someone will be more lucky, than be nice to have link to updated solution.

Comment: What a pity! I really was fascinated by the possibilities that framework offers. But apparently it is useless to spend time in it because you don't know when your code is working again after the next VS update - if at all.

Comment: It should be working in VS 2022: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31348972/210781291-cd602fa5-c267-4b20-b667-344ac239b1f9.png